# UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent[T] () return a null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

this is my start function where i initialise all the attributes of my class

```
void Start()
    {   this._rowCount=0;
        this._ActiveSteps=new List<Steps>();
        this._inActiveSteps=new List<Steps>();
        this._row=new Vector3[5]{new Vector3(-2,-8),new Vector3(-1,-7),new Vector3(0,-6),new Vector3(1,-5),new Vector3(2,-4)};
        this._player=GameObject.Find("Player");  
        this._plyrCollider=this._player.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
        this._Row=new int[4]{2,4,6,8};

       GenerateRow();
       Debug.Log(".ElementAt(0);  "+this._ActiveSteps.ElementAt(0).GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>());
    }
```

also testing with the debug.log which returns a nullreferenceexception but why
if we take a look at the GenerateRow() method we find

```
 public void GenerateRow(){
      foreach(Vector3 pose in _row){
        Steps step=new Steps(pose,true); 
        this._ActiveSteps.Add(step);
        Steps steep=new Steps(pose,false); 
        this._inActiveSteps.Add(step);
      }
    }
```

what am I doing wrong I got lost in this hope I'm not doing some critical primitive mistake

At first, I thought it was this. keyword problem but after fixing it and putting the debug.log after the GenerateRow methods nothing seems to change

Comment: Why do you use `this.` everywhere? Also, where do you add the collider? You call `GetComponent()` to search for it, but where is it added that makes you expect it to be there? Also, shouldn't `this._inActiveSteps.Add(step);` be `this._inActiveSteps.Add(steep);` ? Or do you add the same step to both active and inactive lists?

Comment: I hope that 'this.' would not provoke a big problem I that I can learn the good practice for using oop on Unity the component is manually added on the prefab also thanks for the steep that was a loss that I just now discovered

Comment: `this` is not a *problem*, but it's used in specific cases, not to be spammed in every function. This also comes from the terrible practice I see in many, yet accepted in the community of constructors having the same parameter names as class variables and using `this` to "fix it". Normally, this should be used when you call a function using the current instance of the class. But as I said, it's not a problem, just don't spam it all over the class unless you need to.

Comment: interesting, thank you so much for the more detailed explications that were helpful for future use and for the better understanding I have always needed for more clean and robust work

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately clear to me what is happening since I am not a Unity developer and thus my experience with the framework is quite limited.

However, from the title of your question it seems that it's the call to:

```
GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>()
```

that is causing the exception - i.e. I think it's your Steps class/struct that does not have a 'BoxCollider2D' component (or does not implement the 'BoxCollider2D' interface). Did you by any chance mean to use 'CircleCollider2D' instead? I can see that your **_player** field is using this (for collision detection I presume).

I'm sorry I cannot be of more help at the moment. If you could provide more context (for example the implementation of your Steps class/struct) that might help.

On a closing note, I did observe a few things in your code that may be helpful and/or of interest. Consider the following some friendly advice.

- You have a _rowCount field that seems redundant. Consider removing it. Your collections (**_ActiveSteps** and **_row**, for example) have **Count** or **Length** properties that will tell you the size of each collection.
- Consider providing better names for everything in your code. As your application grows, naming things becomes more important, especially if you are not the only developer working on the code; also, you coming back to your own code after 6 months of not looking at it, will thank you if you do. You have two fields with basically the same names, **_row** and **_Row**, for example; it's not apparent at all what they're supposed to represent or what the difference is between them (are they even related?). They *sound* like the same thing, but are clearly not. Also, on the same note **GenerateRow** is suddenly ambiguous -  does it do stuff to **_row** or **_Row** or both?
- In your **GenerateRow** method, you declare and initialize a variable called **steep**; this is never used, however. Did you mean to use this in the following line **_inActiveSteps.Add(step);**? If so, you could make such issues easier to spot if you name things more appropriately - something like **step** becomes **activeStep** and **steep** becomes **inactiveStep**.

I know you may still just be starting out as a Unity developer (or a developer in general), but make a notice of the above and you'll not only help yourself, but also others, immensely in the future.

Comment: Good job! For someone not using Unity you gave very good advice that can be applied there as well!

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your advices I hope the steep variable didn't get you lost cause that was another problem that you have just solved without even noticing so thanks again.

for the main problem which is the `NullReferenceException` it was in the steps class where I was using the constructor apparently with no return and stores the no-return to the array which makes the active and inactive lists empty even if the program instantiates the `gameobject` with all the components including the collider

```
public Steps(Vector3 position,bool active){ this._position=position;
    this._step=Instantiate (Resources.Load ("Prefab/StepSet")) as GameObject;
    this._grass=_step.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
    this._offSet=_step.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;
  
    this._offSet.transform.localScale=new Vector3( Random.Range(-1,1)<0?-0.6f:0.6f, Random.Range(-1,1)<0?-0.1f:0.1f,1); 
    
    this._grass.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite>("Graphics/_World/_Grass/stepGrass-"+Random.Range(1,3));
    this._grass.transform.localScale=new Vector3( Random.Range(-1,1)<0?-0.6f:0.6f,0.1f,1);

    this._step.transform.position=this._position; 
    //this._step.transform.SetParent(this.transform, false);

}
public GameObject Step(){return this._step;}
```

also, the new version of the code for the GenerateRow method is

```
public void GenerateRow(){
  foreach(Vector3 pose in _row){
    GameObject step=new Steps(pose,true).Step(); 
    this._ActiveSteps.Add(step);
    GameObject steep=new Steps(pose,false).Step(); 
    this._inActiveSteps.Add(steep);
  }
}
```

maybe if i can why not using this. is it causing any problem just cause i wich follow the good practice ^^ trying